# How do I reset credential on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I accidentally typed in the wrong aws-access-id and secret key after running `eb init` when going through the tutorial [Deploying an Express Application to Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html)

Now I am getting the following error "Error: "my-mistyped-key" not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header..."

What is the best way to reset my credential so that I can run "eb init"

Answer (score 4):

go to ~/.aws/config and change your credentials there

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you can find the config file to delete at C:\Users\You\.aws\

You will have to enable viewing hidden files

Answer (score 1):

If you have the AWS CLI installed, type `aws configure` and you can re-enter your credentials.